# How to set referer Header in Guzzle and get CDN Content

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, web-crawler, guzzle

I want to scrape a website and am using guzzle 7.4 and Symfony Dom Crawler

I successfully retrieved the HTML data But the website is using CDN to host some resources and they are not loading because the header is not sent to get those resources

below is code retrieving html

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

// Url
$url = 'scrapingdomain.com';
$headers = [
    'referer' => 'examplescrapingdomain.com'
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => $headers
]);

// go get the data from url
$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$html =  ''.$response->getBody();
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

echo $html;

?>
```

If I access the CDN directly and set referer header I get a response of 200

Below Code

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

// Url
$url = 'examplecdnresource.com/Images.png';
$headers = [
    'referer' => 'examplescrapingdomain.com'
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'headers' => $headers
]);

// go get the data from url
$response = $client->request('GET', $url);
$html =  ''.$response->getBody();
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

echo $html;

?>
```

I want to get the scrapdomain.com get resources and download the cdn hosted images that it has

Comment: It sounds like you know the problem and most of the solution. You will need to download the HTML, then download the resources with the spoofed/forged headers, then rewrite your previously downloaded HTML to point to these resources.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You’ll need to look for some tutorials on screen scraping. You download example.com/index.php, and same that as index.html. Then you parse that, find cdn.example.com/style.css, download and save locally, then update index.html to point to that. Repeat with every resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed to do to get the CDN hosted content inside the scraped html is use file_get_content function and set referer stream to download the data no inside guzzle as i was getting css and image files